# Match Multiple Values (Comma Delimited) Power BI

Tags: csv, powerbi, powerquery, data-transform

[image: Set of data]

I'm working with this set of data, `( articles ID (EID) & authors)`
I would like to match authors or their ID with each ID article .

Example : author 1 : article 1 , article 8 ...

I've no idea how to do this in both M or DAX.
P.S : I tried to split the authors column and unpivot but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is either of these what you are trying to do?

[image]

In powerquery/M:

right click Author ID column, split column by delimiter, semicolon, each occurrence, advanced options, split into rows.  Then filter out the blank rows and remove extra column

Middle Version:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Author(s) ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Author(s) ID"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Delimiter", each ([#"Author(s) ID"] <> "")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Authors with affiliates"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

or, Right version:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Author(s) ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Author(s) ID"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Delimiter", each ([#"Author(s) ID"] <> "")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Authors with affiliates"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Author(s) ID"}, {{"EIDs", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([EID], Text.From), ","), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

Power query has good tools to accomplish this. I don't see a good way to split out the "Authors with affiliations" column in your dataset, so this answer will give you the relationship between the "Author(s) ID" and "EID":

1. Right click on "Author(s) ID" column and select Split Column > By Delimiter
2. Set the delimiter to Semicolon and split at "Each occurrence of the delimiter"
3. In the advanced options, select split into rows

[image: Split Column by Delimiter]

This will create a row for each author ID and EID combination. The "Authors with affiliations" column will have duplicate values.

[image: results]